# agrep function in R

Tags: regex, string, r

I am trying to isolate the strings "24!!07!!10", "15!!08!!12", and "10!!08!!12" from the 4 lines of data below.

```
> z
                                                             LEGAL
1                                                        MAP #1166
2                        SE1/4 NE1/4 24!!07!!10 EX  MAP #106 42.13
3                      MAP 15!!08!!12 N1/2NW1/4 15!!8!!12 80.00 AC
4 BEG NW COR SAID SEC THEN E208' 10!!08!!12 NW1/4 EX TR AC 158.65~
```

Firstly, without the max.distance option the agrep function doesn't find any matches at all. Secondly, the option value=TRUE doesn't seem to give the actual values of the pattern matches and if indeed the output is the indices of the rows, the first row shouldn't really be a match at all.

```
> pattern <-"[0-99]-[0-99]-[0-99]"
> z1<-agrep(pattern ,z,ignore.case=TRUE, value=TRUE)
> z1
character(0)

> z1<-agrep(pattern,z,ignore.case=TRUE, value=TRUE, max.distance=22)
> z1
[1] "c(2, 4, 3, 1)"
```

I'd appreciate any help in figuring out what is going on.

Comment: Your question was nearly unreadable how it was originally formatted. If I've introduced anything you didn't intend, feel free to roll it back. But please note the code formatting tools available to you.

Answer (score 2):

@Kent is right about your regular expression not matching what you describe as your pattern.  In addition, `agrep` is for fuzzy matching in the linguistic sense and does not take regular expressions.  You are looking for `grep` or something in that family, probably `regexpr`.

Given your data

```
z <- c("MAP #1166", 
"SE1/4 NE1/4 24!!07!!10 EX  MAP #106 42.13", 
"MAP 15!!08!!12 N1/2NW1/4 15!!8!!12 80.00 AC", 
"BEG NW COR SAID SEC THEN E208' 10!!08!!12 NW1/4 EX TR AC 158.65~")
```

You can find the locations of the matches and extract them with

```
pattern <- "[0-9][0-9]!![0-9][0-9]!![0-9][0-9]"
locs <- regexpr(pattern, z)
substr(z, locs, locs+attr(locs,"match.length")-1)
```

If you want to use the other form of the regular expression, you can.  You just need to double escape the backslashes in the string literal.

```
pattern <- "\\d{2}!!\\d{2}!!\\d{2}"
```

Comment: Thanks! The locs and substr worked in combination with the as.matrix function as I had 10,000 odd lines of data.

Comment: I may be the annoying person that points that the help file for `agrep` says "a non-empty character string or a character string containing a regular expression" @Brian

Comment: @Rico, In my defense, that change was introduced into r-devel on August 25, 2011, only about a month before my answer. It was not part of a stable release at that point. https://github.com/wch/r-source/commit/d2b80bd76b0433a314897bb4634ee5ca63f2418f That said, you are correct that that part of the answer is rather out of date.

Answer (score 1):

don't know R, but your pattern may be not correct.

how about `"\d{2}!!\d{2}!!\d{2}"`  or

```
"[0-9][0-9]!![0-9][0-9]!![0-9][0-9]"
```

?

Answer (score 1):

Is suspect `agrep` in R doesn't support that kind of pattern. Anyway, you should probably use `grep` instead:

```
z1 <- grep("\\d{2}!!\\d{2}!!\\d{2}", z, value=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use  to try the stringr package

```
require(stringr)

pattern <- "\\d{2}!!\\d{2}!!\\d{2}"
str_extract_all(z, pattern)
```

and you get this :

```
[[1]]
character(0)

[[2]]
[1] "24!!07!!10"

[[3]]
[1] "15!!08!!12"

[[4]]
[1] "10!!08!!12"
```